# Firedac só grava quando fecho a conexão com o banco

Tags: firedac, persistência

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por esse problema.
Utilizo Firedac com Firebird no Rad Studio 10.2 Tokyo, porém já tentei de diversas formas gravar a transação, mas o registro não persiste no banco.

Utilizei este código abaixo como sugere a documentação da Embarcadero, mas nenhuma combinação dele funciona comigo:

```
FDQuery1.CachedUpdates := True;
FDQuery1.Append;
...
FDQuery1.Post;
FDQuery1.Append;
...
FDQuery1.Post;
FDQuery1.Append;
...
FDQuery1.Post;
FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
iErrors := FDQuery1.ApplyUpdates;
if iErrors = 0 then begin
  FDQuery1.CommitUpdates;
  FDConnection1.Commit;
end
else
  FDConnection1.Rollback;
```

Utilizo FDConnection e FDQuery e já tentei usar FDSchemaAdapter, CachedUpdates, mas nenhuma combinação funcionou.
A única solução que funcionou foi desligar e ativar a conexão do banco após o Post da tabela:

```
FDConnection1.Connected := False;
FDConnection1.Connected := True;
```

Eu sempre usei transação com ADOConnection e nunca tive problemas. Mas com Firedac não está funcionando.

Alguém já passou por isto ?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que esta falha do Firedac vem de muitas versões. Achei um aplicativo feito com Firedac em Delphi 2009 que também está com problemas de persistência. Chama-se Admig. Aqui os curiosos podem baixar e se certificar: (https://www.admig.com/setup/setup.exe). Para testar é só abrir o sistema e cadastrar um Novo Membro, depois navegar até a opçao "Grupos" do menu "Ministério" e preencher um novo cadastro. Repare no combobox "Lider" que o novo membro não aparece na lista. Então feche o sistema e logue novamente, e volte ao cadastro de "Grupos". Lá você vai encontrar o nome cadastrado agora. Este é o comportamento que está presente em muitos sistemas feitos com o Firedac. Note que no Admig o desenvolvedor ainda colocou um botão de "Atualizar" em cada tela de cadastro para tentar persistir os dados. Mas nem isto resolveu. O desenvolvedor do Admig utilizou o componente Madshi para gerenciar os erros. De vez em quando aparece a tela de erro e lá a versão do compilador usado e o tipo de componente query utilizado, que neste caso é o Firedac. O relatório do Madshi é bem completo e mostra todos estes detalhes curiosos da aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso Firedac a um bom tempo e nunca tive esse tipo de problema,
mas não quer dizer que não existe. No entanto acho o jeito como
você trata a persistencia de dados "diferente", veja um exmeplo:

Eu geralmente faço assim:

```
FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
Try
  FDQuery1.Append;
  /// Do something ....
  FDQuery1.post;
  FDConnection1.Commit;
Except
  FDConnection1.Rollback
end;
```

Acredito que desse jeito seja mais simples e confiável e não haverá problemas.

Answer (score -4):

Meu problema era justamente o oposto: O Firedac estava commitando tudo sem que eu pudesse controlar. Então comecei a brigar para tentar obter esse controle e só consegui ao inserir a linha "fdconnection.startransaction". Se essa linha for executada o commit só ocorre se eu efetivamente der "FDConnection.Commit", caso contrário nada é gravado no banco.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).